# problem during npm install of a react-native project

Tags: react-native, android-studio, package.json

I have a problem while running the npm install command. Some packages are not in the correct version and I don't know how to fix this problem.
The project is in react-native and I use android studio and the version of npm is v6.14.11 and node is v14.15.4.

```
Applying patches...
No patch files found
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @react-native-community/cameraroll@1.0.3 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.57 <0.59 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-country-picker-modal@1.11.0 requires a peer of react-dom@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-country-picker-modal@1.11.0 requires a peer of react-native-web@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.6 requires a peer of react-native@^0.59.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-fs@2.16.6 requires a peer of react-native-windows@^0.57.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-loader@1.3.1 requires a peer of @react-native-community/art@^1.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-pulse-loader@1.0.3 requires a peer of react-native@^0.27 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-pulse-loader@1.0.3 requires a peer of prop-types@15.6.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-sound-recorder@1.5.0 requires a peer of react-native@^0.46.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-vector-icons@6.7.0 requires a peer of @react-native-community/toolbar-android@^0.1.0-rc.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @sentry/react@5.29.2 requires a peer of react-dom@15.x || 16.x || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view@1.0.1 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.63.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.0.9 requires a peer of react-native-windows@>=0.62 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN modal-react-native-web@0.2.0 requires a peer of react-art@16.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN modal-react-native-web@0.2.0 requires a peer of react-dom@16.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN modal-react-native-web@0.2.0 requires a peer of react-native-web@0.9.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.19.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 1506 packages from 942 contributors and audited 1513 packages in 229.863s

51 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 5 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: These are just warnings not errors.

Answer (score 0):

These are warnings, if you see the final message says that the packages was added successfully :)